# Embed MxPlayer in android layout

Tags: android, android-video-player

My goal is to run a udp stream in a section of an android layout. Playing via MxPlayer is not possible as it runs as a separate application. Any ideas on how to achieve this ?
Can we get MxPlayer library ?

Answer (score 0):

You can play videos using Android's [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) API. If you want more control, check out [`ExoPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html). If embedding is not required you could use an [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and if the user has MxPlayer installed, an option will show to open the stream in MxPlayer.